# Suppose a random sample of size n=2 is generated from a $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ population. Test the following hypothesis

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study

This is a homework problem that I figured having someone explain and solve would be helpful.
Null hypothesis $H_0:\mu =4$, $H_1:\mu \neq 4$. The sample is drawn from ${[x_1, x_2]}={[5,11]}$. Can $H_0$ be rejected at the 1% significance level?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Do I calculate the mean using the sample?

Comment: That is the sample mean, yes.

Comment: So $\sigma$ is unknown, does that mean I use a t statistic?

Comment: Please add the `self-study` tag and read its [tag wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info), altering your question in accordance with the guidelines there. In particular, you should *not* expect solutions, but hints and guidance in return for an explanation of what you've tried and where, specifically, you had difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

Yes since the standard deviation is unknown and sample size is small.. a t test should be used

Comment: consider writing something more. Also notice that the sample is really small $n=2$.

Comment: You're right; a t-test can be used here.  But by "yes" do you really mean to say that $H_0$ ought to be rejected with these data? (Because the sample mean is only $4$ greater than $4$ and the standard error of the sample is $3$, it is obvious that $H_0$ should *not* be rejected at the $1\%$ level, regardless of what test is used.)

Comment: @whuber can you please write up your thoughts into the solution? Would be much appreciated!